# Switch between Stack Exchange sites using the new top bar?

Tags: support, top-bar

With the old Stack Overflow top bar, you could easily switch between sites:

[image: Old top bar]

I've used this option every time I switched between sites. With the new top bar, this option is gone:

[image: New top bar]

I know there are workarounds, like:

- Add a new bookmark for each SO site
- Change URL manually
- Use the 'Related' `div` or the Hot Network Questions

Still, I really miss this functionality from the old top bar and have considered opting out of the beta test for this reason.

Can a similar drop-down function be added to the new top bar? Or does it already exist, and I'm just missing it?

Comment: It's **right there** in the hamburger menu (shaped like the SE logo) on the right. No need to add a menu that already exists.

Comment: it's in the hamburger icon on the right. we know it's now different comparing SO with rest of the network but we're going update layout and structure of top bar globally so it is more inline across network.

Comment: Ah, completely missed that one. Thought it was some kind of chat button, given the icon.

Comment: Yeah, it is a confusing fusion of a hamburger menu and the Stack Exchange logo. Someone was trying to be too clever. I can definitely see why you thought it looked like a "chat" button. I would have stayed away, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is there:

[image: network drop down button]

Click and ye shall have it:

[image: network drop down with popup]

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked that button, instead of leaving it be because of some incorrect prejudice..

Comment: No need to feel bad about it.Icon buttons like these ones are terrible UX as it's often impossible to perceive what lies beneath.

Comment: @Paran0a If it helps, at least on devices where you've got a mouse, I just noticed that these ones have tool tips.