# Is the new Top Bar going to be rolled out to all SE sites in the future?

Tags: support, top-bar

I recently tried out the new top bar and one of the first problems I noticed was the fact that the option to switch to other SE sites is now on the right (which has also caused a little bit of confusion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343260/6214222))

The option being on the right isn't a problem in and of itself, but it's more the fact that this option is on the left on every other SE site (with the current navigation bar), which makes for a horrible experience trying to **quickly** switch between multiple SE sites.

Knowing that this is probably not going to be changed with the new top bar I have to ask: Is it planned to roll out this new navigation design to **all** SE sites in the near future?

I did not find any information on this in the bunch of meta questions I read through, but it's still very possible that I just simply missed it being mentioned somewhere.

Comment: yes, we're planning to update existing top bar on other sites in the network to be more in line with the new one on Stack Overflow. and it's gonna be mostly about structure and layout rather than redesigning it completely (like we did for SO). we don't have exact date for launching it network-wide but it's definitely on our roadmap.

Comment: Here is a detailed blog post about: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/14/why-stack-overflow-redesigned-the-top-navigation/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Top bar updates are coming to the rest of the Stack Exchange network in the next couple weeks (Sept 2017). [Check the details here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network).

Answer (score 8):

As [Paweł ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1147887/pawe%C5%82) notes in [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343260/switch-between-stack-exchange-sites-using-the-new-top-bar#comment444470_343260) to [the very question you linked to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343260/switch-between-stack-exchange-sites-using-the-new-top-bar):

> [...] we know it's now different comparing SO with rest of the network but we're going update layout and structure of top bar globally so it is more inline across network.