# Temporary option to revert to old nav bar (switching sites is disorienting)

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

Personally, I love the new nav bar. I'm excited about it, and I'm looking forward to seeing it on other sites.

*However*, because only [M]SO uses it, I'm finding that I'm mentally having a *really* hard time switching between SO and other sites. I don't mind either nav bar, but the switch is jarring. It's especially intense when you are e.g. clicking through your inbox reading items in order, going back and forth between SO and other sites. I use a lot of the SE sites frequently, I'm often jumping back and forth. It's really throwing me for a loop.

So I would like to ask for a *temporary* option to revert to the old nav bar, only for this reason (to ease some of the UX woes when switching among many SE sites), with the understanding that I actually do like the new bar, but the constant switching is rough. The option should go away once the new nav bar is [rolled out to the rest of the sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343268/616460).

This is, of course, assuming that the roll-out won't happen for another 6-8 weeks. If it's coming up soon, disregard this.

Comment: Meanwhile, I do use two tabs in chrome, one for SO/MSO, one for the others sites.